# Wordpress theme design issue

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

My website is built, (graphically designed) to be compact. Because my background will not look good on repeat, fixed, or with a white/black gradient towards the bottom. The thing is, I need to have a fixed content area, because of the graphical nature of my site. A box, which has to remain the same size, at all times. So, my question is, can I use wordpress, in such a way, that I will get a sort of iframe, within my content area, without the content area dragging on for how long the content is ? Let me show you an example of what I want : http://s15.postimage.org/obk0ivffv/2352366d.png

Can this be done, in wordpress ? Through CSS or something ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your content in a div, and set a max-height and overflow-y:scroll on that container with css.

Edit: fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/Kncy6/

Comment: My gosh ! This truly shows, how much of a noob I am. THANK YOU !

Comment: I pressed enter for a new row. lol. I wanted to add.. the thing that remains now to ask, is.. can I make this inside the wordpress theme ? Because it works in a different code style.

Comment: It still uses HTML and CSS, so anything is possible! Just find the correct template file and add the div that will act as the container.

Comment: Thank you. I found it. It's in the style.css, (duh for me)